# datetime.strptime based on regex pattern check

Tags: python, datetime

I am working with the below function

```
def convStr2Date(given):

    if type(given) != str:
        return given
    pattern = r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|.*)'
    rv = re.search(pattern, given).group(1)
    if rv:
        return datetime.strptime(rv, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

which gives me the error `ValueError: time data '2021-10-01' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

So I added an `else:` statement, but still getting the same error, where am I going wrong?

Trying:

```
def convStr2Date(given):
    if type(given) != str:
        return given
    pattern = r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|.*)'
    rv = re.search(pattern, given).group(1)
    if rv:
        return datetime.strptime(rv, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        return datetime.strptime(rv, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: [isn't the `|.*` allowing the regex](https://regex101.com/r/oQG43B/1) to also just match literally anything other than newline? if you just remove that does it work as you expect?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Except the regex is to prevent the error from occuring

Comment: In this case you could also do re.search("^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})( \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?", "2021-10-01").group(1) and always use datetime.strptime(rv, '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I removed the `|.*` from the pattern line and now getting error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Or test for rv.group(2)

Comment: When you remove the |.* the regex is no longer ALWAYS matching. In this case if the regex does not match, you get and Error  which you can catch with try and except

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return None (or an Error) if nothing is matching (instead of just accepting everything) you can also do

```
def convStr2Date(given):
    if type(given) != str:
        return given
    pattern =  '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})( \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?$'
    rv = re.search(pattern, given)
    if rv and rv.group(2): # Tests if second group matches
                           # (the part with the time of day)
                           # So there is given both date and time of day
        return datetime.strptime(rv.group(0), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    elif rv:               # Tests if the whole regex matches.
                           # Since the second part is optional
                           # the regex still matches if it is missing
                           # and because the first if tests if the
                           # second part exists and we are in the else branch
                           # we know only the first group matches
                           # which is only the date (without time)
        return datetime.strptime(given, '%Y-%m-%d')
    else:                  # If the whole regex does not match
                           # we know that it is not one of the two formats
                           # and therefore cannot be parsed
        return None # Or raise some Error
        #raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: This is definitely the most correct answer, the real key that should be highlighted is that the regex will match a date or a date-time and nothing else which are the 2 formats that are desired to be parsed.

Comment: Thanks, works! would you mind explaining or putting some comments on each line? My brain is having a hard time following!

Comment: I hope the comments are good enough to understand what is happening

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about exact patterns, you could just test for a space. Your code is going to fail on other date patterns anyway.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convStr2Date(given: str) -> datetime:
  if not isinstance(given, str):
    raise ValueError(f"{given!r} is not a string")
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
  if ' ' in given :
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  return datetime.strptime(given, date_format)
```

Example

```py
for d in ['2021-10-02', '2018-10-20 01:21:23', 'not a date', 'notADate', 2, None]:
  try:
    print(convStr2Date(d)) 
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output

```
2021-10-02 00:00:00
2018-10-20 01:21:23
time data 'not a date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
time data 'notADate' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
2 is not a string
None is not a string
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP was looking for, this only works when the entire string is the date where as using `re.search` could generalize to strings like `"the date is 2021-01-02"` which contains a space but should be parsed only the part that looks like a date.

Comment: True, but only input value we were given was `'2021-10-01'`

Answer (score 0):

remove the `|.*` so that it will only match dates and then if it doesn't match it will return `None` so you need to ensure that is not the case before using it for things like `.group(1)`

```
def convStr2Date(given: str):
    pattern = r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
    match = re.search(pattern, given)
    if match is not None:
        # only call group if the match exists
        return datetime.strptime(match.group(1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else:raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Thanks. Why get rid of `group(1)`? Also shouldnt match be in your return line? not given?

Comment: yep sorry I was confusing myself, the issue is that when the string is invalid `match` will be `None` so you can't call any methods on it, so you need to ensure it isn't none before using it.

Comment: ah i see, i ran it, getting not implemented!

Comment: Does not work for the case without time of day

Comment: @Kumpelinus , correct. But I want it to work for cases with both time of day and not.

Comment: @Kumpelinus I'm still not 100% clear on what the intended behaviour is, putting `strptime(given, '%Y-%m-%d')` where the `raise` currently is that might do what is expected but if a string like `"the date is 2021-11-01"` is suppose to work then something entirely different would be needed.

Comment: Then take a look at @OneCricketeer or my answer

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen That is True, and that is why I used Groups to check all three cases. You can also just assume that it is just one of the 2 (maybe desired) and don't handle this case